# Index column based on column value in grouped data

Tags: powerquery

I'm trying to generate an index column in grouped data based on a text value.

What I currently have is this:

```
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows1",{{"Source.Name", type text}, {"Team", type text}, {"Project category", type text}, {"Project type", type text}, {"Role", type text}, {"Month", type text}, {"Value", type number}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Team", "Project category", "Month"}, {{"Count", each _, type table [Source.Name=nullable text, Team=nullable text, Project category=nullable text, Project type=nullable text, Role=nullable text, Month=nullable text, Value=nullable number, Index=number]}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([Count], "#FCST", 1, 1))
```

Here is a subtable:

[Subtable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJuib.png)

What I would like is very similar, but I would like the index (#FCST here) on the subtable to be incremented only when the value in Source.Name changes.

In this case the first 2 rows should stay as 1 and the 3th and 4th rows should be 2.

Comment: Please paste your sample data as text

Comment: Sorry for that, here you go!

Team Project category Project type Role Month Value
SW Licensing Roadmap VS Installation & Onboarding Lead August 2022 0
SW Licensing Roadmap VS Installation & Onboarding Lead September 2022 0
SW Licensing Roadmap VS Installation & Onboarding Lead October 2022 0
SW Licensing Roadmap VS Installation & Onboarding Arch August 2022 0
SW Licensing Roadmap VS Installation & Onboarding Arch September 2022 0
SW Licensing Roadmap VS Installation & Onboarding Arch October 2022 0
SW Licensing Roadmap VS Installation & Onboarding Resources August 2022 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Group the table by Source.Name using Aggregation = 'All Rows':
   [image]
2. Add an index column, starting at 1, to the table in the second column (grouped)
   [image]
3. Remove the grouped column (don't need it any more since 'Custom' is the same + the index column
   [image]
4. For simplicity in the next step, define a list of column headers (adjust as necessary:
   [image]
5. Expand the table column:
   [image]

Here's the code for the advanced editor:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

    //group by Source.Name and return All Rows as the aggregation
    grouped = Table.Group(
                Source,
                {"Source.Name"},
                {{"grouped", each _, 
                    type table [Source.Name=text, Team=text, Project category=text, Project type=text, 
                                Role=text, Month=datetime, Value=any, Column1=text, #"#FCST"=number]}}),

    //add an Index starting at 1 column to the 'All rows' aggregation 
    added_group_index = Table.AddColumn(grouped, "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([grouped],"#FCST_BY_FILE",1)),

    //remove the unnecessary column
    removed_columns = Table.RemoveColumns(added_group_index,{"grouped"}),

    //to use in the next statement
    cols = {"Team", "Project category", "Project type", "Role", "Month", "Value", "Column1", "#FCST", "#FCST_BY_FILE"},

    //expand the new table with the Index by file name
    expand_table = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
                        removed_columns, //table to expand from
                        "Custom", //column to expand
                        cols, //columns
                        cols //new column names
                    ) 
in
    expand_table
```

Comment: Unforunately this solution doesn't work because Source.Name is apparently not included in the subtable generated by GroupedRows.

Comment: What error are you seeing? It works for me.

Comment: Expression.Error: The column 'Source. Name ' of the table wasn't found. 

The issue is that the subtable I have shared doesn't seem to be seen as a type Table by PowerQuery actually. This subtable already originates from a Group By operation BTW.

Comment: OK. Your 'Source. Name' has a space in it. 

The code I posted works. Hopefully you will be able to adapt it for your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately removing spaces doesn't change anything, because your code is to be performed on primary data but I'm working on a subtable.

It should be sthg of this kind to work "#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([Count], "#FCST", 1, 1))", it cannot be each _ because _ refers to the primary table I believe.

Comment: In other words the screenshot I have attached at the beginning is already the result of a group by operation, this is not my raw table. 
I'm trying to index grouped data with an IF condition if you prefer.

Answer (score -2):

I finally solved my issue with this trick :

```
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Team", "Project category", "Month"}, {{"Count", each _, type table [Source.Name=nullable text, Team=nullable text, Project category=nullable text, Project type=nullable text, Role=nullable text, Month=nullable text, Value=nullable number, Index=number]}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddRankColumn([Count], "#FCST", {"Source.Name", Order.Ascending}, [RankKind = RankKind.Dense])),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Project type", "Role", "Value", "#FCST"}, {"Project type", "Role", "Value", "#FCST"}),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).